# ORCA failed during NEB-TS ONIOM

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orca, optimization, transition-state

Thanks in advance for any help provided. I was trying to find the transition state of a diels alder reaction and considering my system's bulkiness I wanted to try a NEB calculation considering part of the structure in QM (MN15/DEF2-SVP) and part in MM. Unexpectedly at the end it failed, even if the MEP seemed quite right.

I cannot find anything on this type of error, any advice would be appreciated :)

```
   LBFGS    48      4    0.042926    0.057420   0.003170  165.8529    0.027242    0.003767       
   LBFGS    49      4    0.043722    0.071380   0.004063  165.8515    0.041807    0.004877       
   LBFGS    50      6    0.048872    0.071381   0.004367  165.8515    0.005908    0.000851       
[file orca_tools/Tool-Misc/qcneb.cpp, line 540]: Error (ORCA/NEB): Failure in L-BFGS (division by very small number)
```

To be even more clear this was the neb.inp

````
! QM/QM2  def2-svp NEB-TS cpcm(toluene) 

%neb
    TS "ts.xyz"
    product "product.xyz"
    preopt true
    nimages 8 
    NEB_TS_Image 4
end

%method
    method dft
    functional hyb_mgga_x_mn15
end

%pal
    nprocs 44
end

%maxcore 4000

%qmmm
    QM2CustomMethod "pbe"
    QM2CustomBasis "def2-svp"
    QMAtoms { 14 15 16 18 32:34 56:63 64:82 83:91 } end # atomi da trattare a MN15
    #14-18 caten cat. 32-34 hyd. 56-63 acido 64-82 diene 83-91 mal.
end

*xyzfile 0 1 reagents.xyz
```
````

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! Could you please paste the input file into a `code` block rather than giving us a screenshot? The screenshot is not visible on all browsers, especially ones that use screen-readers or image-blockers.

Comment: @Laura could you also add the input xyz files as code blocks? This would help people to replicate your problem in order to get a solution.